# How to get html content of a input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input tag:

```
<input type="text" value="04/09/2013" class="date-time-date width-100 hasDatepicker" name="booking_info[to_time_24_date]" id="to_time_24_date" readonly="readonly">
```

i need to get all the content in input tag (all content shown above) but when i use

```
$('#to_time_24_date').html();
```

it returns nothing. How can i get this content?

Comment: do you want to get the value of the input tag..?? then use `$('#to_time_24_date').val();`

Comment: if you want to get the values of attributes like class, id , type etc use $('#to_time_24_date').attr('name') etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('to_time_24_date').outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple method in order to get all of your input field HTML:

```
$('#to_time_24_date').get(0).outerHTML;
```

I have made a JsFiddle Test Demo for you, Please follow this link. It will give the same thing you are looking for, in alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/jpaYK/

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `outerHTML` property.

```
$('#to_time_24_date').get(0).outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

```
$('#to_time_24_date').get(0).outerHTML; // $('#to_time_24_date')[0].outerHTML;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sKJRS/)

without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('to_time_24_date').outerHTML
```

Comment: no he can't, outerHTML isn't a real HTML property and isn't supported by several browsers, unlike innerHTML.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML#compat-desktop

Answer (score 0):

`html()` gets the inner HTML, HTML of the elements inside this element.

Check the answer here:

[Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

The accepted answer uses a nice trick in the answer to this question. It creates another element (but doesn't add it to the page), clones the element it wants inside the created element, and then gets the inner HTML of the created element, which is the HTML of the clone, which is the same HTML of the element we want.

```
$("<div>").append($('#to_time_24_date').eq(0).clone()).html();
// or
$("<div>").append(document.getElementById('#to_time_24_date').clone()).html();
```

However, see other answers as well, turns out there is a simpler way you can try too, there's a property `outerHTML` you can use as:

```
$('#to_time_24_date')[0].outerHTML
```

Which has decent browser support as per:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "<input";
$.each($("#"+to_time_24_date)[0].attributes, function(i, attr){
    html += ' '+attr.name+'="'+attr.value+'"';
});
html += " />";
alert(html);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHX4Z/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="04/09/2013" class="date-time-date width-100 hasDatepicker" name="booking_info[to_time_24_date]" id="to_time_24_date" readonly="readonly">
```

This does not have any "Content" or "HTML" it does have attributes, and you can get the attributes with the attr method from jQuery.. $('input[type="text"]').attr('id'); would return the id attribute.

If you are just looking for the entered value of the input tag (what is typed in) then use $('input[type="text"]').val(); to get the value.

I hope this helps

here's a jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/LUep8/